# Search by ObjectId in mongoose schema nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using mongoose with nodejs . I have item schema and user schema given below.

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  items : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Item' }]
});

var itemSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  _owner : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
});
```

**I am trying to find item by user id(`_owner` in item schema).**

I have tried to find directly

```
var uid = req.decoded._id;
var item = Item.findOne({"_owner": uid});
console.log(item.name);   // undefined
```

By searching similar I found that id needs to be in ObjectId object so I tried

```
var uid = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.decoded._id);
var item = Item.findOne({"_owner": uid});
console.log(item.name);   // undefined
```

In both the cases `item.name` is undefined .Note that I have rechecked the value of `req.decoded._id`(by printing) with the db so it not undefined and present in db.

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Model.findOne`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) is an async call. It doesn't return the doc, it passes it to a callback function that you need to provide as a second parameter.

```
var uid = req.decoded._id;
var item = Item.findOne({"_owner": uid}, function(err, item) {
    console.log(item.name);
});
```

Comment: thanks for pointing me to right direction it worked but `uid` should be `var uid = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.decoded._id);` . Update your answer so that I can accept it

Comment: @singhakash Actually, Mongoose will perform the casting `uid` for you based on the way `_owner` is defined in the schema, so that's unnecessary.